# Drupal + Solr, how to boost search results with updated date?

Tags: 7, hooks, search

I'm trying to boost search results to give more relevancy to newly updated / created content. What I have tried is to use the following:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook search_api_solr_query_alter
 */
function mml_search_search_api_solr_query_alter(array &$call_args, SearchApiQueryInterface $query) {
  // Boost by changed date. Fresher to top.
  $call_args['params']['freshness'] = 'recip(abs(ms(NOW/HOUR,ds_changed)),3.16e-11,10,1)';
}
```

But it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is screenshot of solr admin side of the "field" Im trying to boost http://monosnap.com/image/A3c6WOGi71z0Smeke8tYgBbnoeNkyK

Comment: I could do with finding this out as well .  I was wondering if in 

> admin > config > search > Search api > index > % > fields  .  If I was to change the created from type 'date' to 'string' that I'd then be able to add it to the Boost and weighting.  I don't want to test this on a live site though.

Comment: @Tuomas_Leppänen have you had any joy with this issue and finding a solution.

Comment: @Deejay sorry but nope.

Comment: looking at the arguments I'm receiving in my code for this hook; I haven't got a value for $call_args['params']['freshness']

in $call_args['params']['qf'] is where I get an array of values that list the weights for the boost.

Comment: As a work-around you could set up a sort based on change date and default to that, works for us.

Comment: @Darvanen if you mean sorting by date in the view before passing to relevance, then this doesn't work for us.  As we want to pass the relevance by Title first ; then date; then body.

Comment: after reading http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/date-boosting-solr-drupal-search-results & 'date boosting' at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery .  the line '$call_args['params']['qf'][] = 'recip(abs(ms(NOW,ds_changed)),3.16e-11,1,1)';' I think should work but doesn't .

Comment: @Tuomas Leppänen  are you still working on this.  Here's where I am with it . https://www.drupal.org/node/2392499  . I'm now starting work on making a UI extension for the fields page but could do with getting this hook to work first.  How about opening a chat page on here for it.

Comment: Project extension proposed if anyone's interested in this one https://www.drupal.org/node/2395563

Answer (score 2):

This module may be a solution https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_sorts

Otherwise using you method above - According to this post http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/date-boosting-solr-drupal-search-results

then you need to add an extra []

```
$call_args['params']['freshness'][] = 'recip(abs(ms(NOW/HOUR,ds_changed)),3.16e-11,10,1)';
```

However after testing I still can get the result I want.

For example the value 3.16e-11,10 ; as far as I understand it means a year of milliseconds that gives a score of 10 inside that time span. and then decrease after.

For testing I used

```
call_args['params']['qf'][] = 'recip(abs(ms(NOW/HOUR,ds_changed)),86400000,21,1)';
```

which should give Posts added/changed on the day a score of 21 and then decreases daily.

Testing with 3 identical listings.  And only title set at a boost rate over 1.  I cannot get the articles to listing in date. order. Have i missed something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

In hook_apachesolr_query_prepare,add ur indexed field with ur weightage using param **`bf`**.
This hook is similar to the query_alter but runs before the query is cached

Reference to parameters https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters

```
  /**
     * Prepare the query by adding parameters, sorts, etc.
     *
     * This hook is invoked before the query is cached. The cached query is used
     * after the search such as for building facet and sort blocks, so parameters
     * added during this hook may be visible to end users.
     *
     * This is otherwise the same as HOOK_apachesolr_query_alter(), but runs before
     * it.
     *
     * @param object $query
     *  An object implementing DrupalSolrQueryInterface. No need for &.
     */

function module_apachesolr_query_prepare(DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query) {
     $query->addParam('bq','indexedFieldName^20');  
     watchdog("solrquery", '<pre>' . print_r( $query, true) . '</pre>');
}
```

I have used

```
 $query->addParam('bq','tm_display_name^20');
```

bq: Boost Query: specifies a factor by which a term or phrase should be "boosted" in importance when considering a match.

Where solrquery obj results like that

```
   [bq] => Array
                (
                    [0] => tm_display_name^40
                )
```

Assuming that field is already indexed in our solr.

Use that hook. Then search for a content. In recent log message 'solrquery',check 
whether your field is added in bq

Have added the link for you reference.
http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/boosting-solr-search-results-query-time

Comment: If it is an answer to the question. please add some description  to it.

Comment: @orchid thank you for the reply. We have this issue on Search API Solr (drupal.org/project/search_api_solr
) and not the Apache Solr Search module(drupal.org/project/apachesolr); so I'm not 100% sure of the relevance of this reply to our issue.